# Laravel language files. Catch missing definitions

Tags: laravel-4, localization

I am using Laravel's language capability in my app.

The problem I have is that if I call a language line the does not exist, the return value is the key used e.g.

```
Lang::get('messages.doesNotExist');

returns 'messages.doesNotExist'
```

Does Laravel provide any way to find out if language lines are missing? e.g. logging missing lines to an error log?

My concern is that I may not realize language lines are missing unless a user flags it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From docs (http://laravel.com/docs/localization#basic-usage):

> **Determine If A Language File Contains A Line**
>
> ```
> if (Lang::has('messages.doesNotExist'))
> {
>     //
> }
> ```

Comment: hmm not really what I was after. I was hoping I'd over looked something and that laravel would provide a check when I call Lang::get('messages.doesNotExist'); and  then log as an error is it doesnt exist

Comment: Will test if this method still works, but I'd like to note this method listed in the doc link that is posted (Laravel 5.1)

Comment: You can find the **has()** in the documentation: [Translator](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.html#method_has)

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of [Lost in Translation](https://packagist.org/packages/kinoritech/lost-in-translation), which can analyze your code and localization files to find both missing translations and unused keys. After installing and adding it to the service providers (as explained in the README), you can use the `locale:scan` artisan command to generate a report of the localization use. Such as:

```
$ php artisan locale:scan
Preparing files
Looking in /git/lost-in-translation-wrapper/app and git/lost-in-translation-wrapper/resources
Searching translationkeys in 51 files
 51/51 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓] 100%
Found 23 translations.
There are missing translations.
+----------------------------------------------+-------+-----------+---------+
| Key                                          | Group | Namespace | Missing |
+----------------------------------------------+-------+-----------+---------+
| failed                                       | auth  | *         | fr      |
| throttle                                     | auth  | *         | fr      |
| password                                     | auth  | *         | fr      |
| Email                                        | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Password                                     | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Confirm Password                             | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Reset Password                               | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Name                                         | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Already registered?                          | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Register                                     | *     | *         | es      |
| This is a secure area of the application     | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Confirm                                      | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Forgot your password? No problem             | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Email Password Reset Link                    | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Thanks for signing up! Before getting st ... | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| A new verification link has been sent to ... | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Resend Verification Email                    | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Log Out                                      | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Remember me                                  | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Forgot your password?                        | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Log in                                       | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Whoops! Something went wrong                 | *     | *         | es, fr  |
| Dashboard                                    | *     | *         | es, fr  |
+----------------------------------------------+-------+-----------+---------+
There are unused translations.
*.*.I love programming.
*.auth.invalid
```